# Probability that a King of hearts will be chosen, given there is a king

Tags: probability, card-games

I am currently stuck on this question and how it would be worked out.

I currently have the probaility that at least one king will be 0.341

And that the probability of drawing a King of hearts is 51 c 1 / 52 c 5  [editted! I typed it wrong 51 c 4 / 52 c 5]

But the following question is stumping me a bit,

A hand of five cards is dealt from a normal pack of 52 cards. Find the probability that the hand will contain   the king of hearts, given that there is at least one king.

Thanks,

Comment: $\frac {51 \choose 1}{52 \choose 5}=\frac 1{50960}$.  The chance you draw the King of Hearts on the first draw is $\frac 1{52}$, so what you have is badly wrong.

Comment: Whoops, I mean 51 C 4 / 52 C 5

Comment: Can you convert that to a reasonable fraction?  It will give you some intuition where it comes from.  However, I don't think it is useful.  One approach is what is the chance you draw exactly one king?  Of those, what is the chance it is the king of hearts?  What is the chance you draw two kings?  What is the chance one is the king of hearts? and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: There are $\binom{48}5$ hands with no king, so there are $\binom{52}5-\binom{48}5$ hands with at least one king. There are $\binom{51}4$ hands that contain the king of hearts. Can you put those pieces together to get the desired probability?

Comment: Perfect, thank you.
52 C 5 - 48 C 5 divided by 51 C 4.  
Loving the fact it was a hint too, thanks! :)

Comment: @Mathsider: You’re welcome!